# Unable to upgrade Ubuntu 22.04 from Ubuntu 20.04

Tags: 20.04, upgrade, 22.04, openssl

during the upgarde there were some errors related to usrmerge. now i don't know how to fix it

```
iulian@iulian-md:~$ sudo do-release-upgrade

Checking for a new Ubuntu release
There is no development version of an LTS available.
To upgrade to the latest non-LTS development release 
set Prompt=normal in /etc/update-manager/release-upgrades.
iulian@iulian-md:~$ sudo apt --fix-broken install
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree... Done
Reading state information... Done
Correcting dependencies... Done
The following packages were automatically installed and are no longer required:
  coinor-libcbc3 coinor-libcgl1 coinor-libclp1 coinor-libcoinmp1v5 coinor-libcoinutils3v5 coinor-libosi1v5 cryptsetup-run fonts-inter gcc-10-base gcc-10-base:i386
  gir1.2-clutter-gst-3.0 gir1.2-gtkclutter-1.0 gir1.2-handy-0.0 i965-va-driver:i386 intel-media-va-driver:i386 kde-cli-tools kde-cli-tools-data libamtk-5-0
  libamtk-5-common libaom0 libaom0:i386 libaom3:i386 libarmadillo9 libasn1-8-heimdal:i386 libasync-mergepoint-perl libavcodec58:i386 libavutil56:i386
  libboost-date-time1.71.0 libboost-filesystem1.71.0 libboost-iostreams1.71.0 libboost-locale1.71.0 libbrlapi0.7 libcbor0.6 libcdio18 libcfitsio8 libcloudproviders0
  libcodec2-0.9 libcodec2-0.9:i386 libcodec2-1.0:i386 libcurl3-gnutls:i386 libdap25 libdap27 libdapclient6v5 libdav1d5:i386 libdc1394-22 libdcmtk14 libdns-export1109
  libdrm-intel1:i386 libdvdread7 libepsilon1 libextutils-pkgconfig-perl libffi7:i386 libfluidsynth2 libfuture-perl libgdal26 libgdbm-compat4:i386 libgdbm6:i386
  libgdk-pixbuf-xlib-2.0-0:i386 libgdk-pixbuf2.0-0:i386 libgeos-3.8.0 libgles2-mesa-dev libglew2.1 libglu1-mesa:i386 libgomp1:i386 libgssapi3-heimdal:i386 libgupnp-1.2-0
  libhandy-0.0-0 libhcrypto4-heimdal:i386 libhdf5-103 libhdf5-fortran-102 libhdf5-hl-fortran-100 libheimbase1-heimdal:i386 libheimntlm0-heimdal:i386 libhogweed5
  libhogweed5:i386 libhx509-5-heimdal:i386 libicu66:i386 libieee1284-3:i386 libigdgmm11 libigdgmm11:i386 libigdgmm12:i386 libilmbase24 libio-async-loop-epoll-perl
  libio-async-perl libjson-c4 libkf5attica5 libkf5pty-data libkf5pty5 libkf5pulseaudioqt2 libkf5su-bin libkf5su-data libkf5su5 libkrb5-26-heimdal:i386 libkworkspace5-5
  libldap-2.4-2:i386 liblinux-epoll-perl libllvm12 libllvm12:i386 libmetrics-any-perl libmozjs-68-0 libmysqlclient21:i386 libnetcdf15 libnettle7 libnettle7:i386
  libnspr4:i386 libnss3:i386 libntfs-3g883 libnuma1:i386 libodbc1 libodbc1:i386 libodbccr2 libodbccr2:i386 libofa0 libopencv-core4.2 libopencv-imgcodecs4.2
  libopencv-imgproc4.2 libopencv-videoio4.2 libopenexr24 libopengl0:i386 libopenimageio2.1 libopenjp2-7:i386 libopenvdb6.2 libpangox-1.0-0 libpci3:i386 libpciaccess0:i386
  libpcre2-posix2 libperl5.30 libperl5.30:i386 libperl5.34:i386 libpgm-5.2-0 libpoppler-glib8:i386 libpoppler118:i386 libpoppler97 libproj15 libpython3.8 libpython3.8-dev
  libpython3.8-minimal libpython3.8-stdlib libqhull7 libqpdf26 libraw19 libre2-5 libreadonly-perl libref-util-perl libref-util-xs-perl libroken18-heimdal:i386 libsane
  libsane:i386 libsane1:i386 libsereal-perl libshine3:i386 libsnappy1v5:i386 libsnmp35 libsnmp40:i386 libsoxr0:i386 libsrt1 libstruct-dumb-perl libswresample3:i386
  libtepl-4-0 libtest-fatal-perl libtest-metrics-any-perl libtest-refcount-perl libtinyxml2-6a libtracker-control-2.0-0 libtracker-miner-2.0-0 libtype-tiny-perl
  libtype-tiny-xs-perl libusrsctp1 libva-drm2:i386 libva-x11-2:i386 libva2:i386 libvdpau1:i386 libvpx6:i386 libwebp6:i386 libwebpmux3:i386 libwind0-heimdal:i386
  libwrap0:i386 libx264-155 libx264-155:i386 libx264-163:i386 libx265-179 libx265-179:i386 libx265-199:i386 libxml-writer-perl libxmlb1 libxvidcore4:i386 libyaml-cpp0.6
  libzvbi0:i386 mesa-va-drivers:i386 mesa-vdpau-drivers:i386 nextcloud-desktop-doc odbcinst odbcinst1debian2 perl-modules-5.30 python-pip-whl python-wxgtk3.0
  python-wxversion python3-entrypoints python3-simplebayes python3-termcolor python3.8 python3.8-dev python3.8-minimal va-driver-all:i386 vdpau-driver-all:i386
  x11proto-input-dev x11proto-randr-dev x11proto-xext-dev x11proto-xinerama-dev
Use 'sudo apt autoremove' to remove them.
The following packages will be REMOVED:
  libsnmp35:i386 libssl1.1:i386
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 2 to remove and 1 not upgraded.
4 not fully installed or removed.
After this operation, 8.231 kB disk space will be freed.
Do you want to continue? [Y/n] y
(Reading database ... 313189 files and directories currently installed.)
Removing libsnmp35:i386 (5.8+dfsg-2ubuntu2.5) ...
Removing libssl1.1:i386 (1.1.1f-1ubuntu2.16) ...
Setting up libssl1.1:amd64 (1.1.1l-1ubuntu1) ...
Setting up usrmerge (25ubuntu2) ...
Smartmatch is experimental at /usr/lib/usrmerge/convert-usrmerge line 172.

FATAL ERROR:
Both /lib/libeToken.so.10 and /usr/lib/libeToken.so.10 exist.

You can try correcting the errors reported and running again
/usr/lib/usrmerge/convert-usrmerge until it will complete without errors.
Do not install or update other Debian packages until the program
has been run successfully.

dpkg: error processing package usrmerge (--configure):
 installed usrmerge package post-installation script subprocess returned error exit status 1
Setting up openssl (1.1.1f-1ubuntu2.16) ...
Installing new version of config file /etc/ssl/openssl.cnf ...
Processing triggers for libc-bin (2.35-0ubuntu3.1) ...
Errors were encountered while processing:
 usrmerge
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
iulian@iulian-md:~$
```

after i tried it too

```
iulian@iulian-md:~$ sudo apt autoremove
[sudo] password for iulian: 
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree... Done
Reading state information... Done
The following packages will be REMOVED:
  coinor-libcbc3 coinor-libcgl1 coinor-libclp1 coinor-libcoinmp1v5
  coinor-libcoinutils3v5 coinor-libosi1v5 cryptsetup-run fonts-inter
  gcc-10-base gcc-10-base:i386 gir1.2-clutter-gst-3.0 gir1.2-gtkclutter-1.0
  gir1.2-handy-0.0 i965-va-driver:i386 intel-media-va-driver:i386
  kde-cli-tools kde-cli-tools-data libamtk-5-0 libamtk-5-common libaom0
  libaom0:i386 libaom3:i386 libarmadillo9 libasn1-8-heimdal:i386
  libasync-mergepoint-perl libavcodec58:i386 libavutil56:i386
  libboost-date-time1.71.0 libboost-filesystem1.71.0 libboost-iostreams1.71.0
  libboost-locale1.71.0 libbrlapi0.7 libcbor0.6 libcdio18 libcfitsio8
  libcloudproviders0 libcodec2-0.9 libcodec2-0.9:i386 libcodec2-1.0:i386
  libcurl3-gnutls:i386 libdap25 libdap27 libdapclient6v5 libdav1d5:i386
  libdc1394-22 libdcmtk14 libdns-export1109 libdrm-intel1:i386 libdvdread7
  libepsilon1 libextutils-pkgconfig-perl libffi7:i386 libfluidsynth2
  libfuture-perl libgdal26 libgdbm-compat4:i386 libgdbm6:i386
  libgdk-pixbuf-xlib-2.0-0:i386 libgdk-pixbuf2.0-0:i386 libgeos-3.8.0
  libgles2-mesa-dev libglew2.1 libglu1-mesa:i386 libgomp1:i386
  libgssapi3-heimdal:i386 libgupnp-1.2-0 libhandy-0.0-0
  libhcrypto4-heimdal:i386 libhdf5-103 libhdf5-fortran-102
  libhdf5-hl-fortran-100 libheimbase1-heimdal:i386 libheimntlm0-heimdal:i386
  libhogweed5 libhogweed5:i386 libhx509-5-heimdal:i386 libicu66:i386
  libieee1284-3:i386 libigdgmm11 libigdgmm11:i386 libigdgmm12:i386
  libilmbase24 libio-async-loop-epoll-perl libio-async-perl libjson-c4
  libkf5attica5 libkf5pty-data libkf5pty5 libkf5pulseaudioqt2 libkf5su-bin
  libkf5su-data libkf5su5 libkrb5-26-heimdal:i386 libkworkspace5-5
  libldap-2.4-2:i386 liblinux-epoll-perl libllvm12 libllvm12:i386
  libmetrics-any-perl libmozjs-68-0 libmysqlclient21:i386 libnetcdf15
  libnettle7 libnettle7:i386 libnspr4:i386 libnss3:i386 libntfs-3g883
  libnuma1:i386 libodbc1 libodbc1:i386 libodbccr2 libodbccr2:i386 libofa0
  libopencv-core4.2 libopencv-imgcodecs4.2 libopencv-imgproc4.2
  libopencv-videoio4.2 libopenexr24 libopengl0:i386 libopenimageio2.1
  libopenjp2-7:i386 libopenvdb6.2 libpangox-1.0-0 libpci3:i386
  libpciaccess0:i386 libpcre2-posix2 libperl5.30 libperl5.30:i386
  libperl5.34:i386 libpgm-5.2-0 libpoppler-glib8:i386 libpoppler118:i386
  libpoppler97 libproj15 libpython3.8 libpython3.8-dev libpython3.8-minimal
  libpython3.8-stdlib libqhull7 libqpdf26 libraw19 libre2-5 libreadonly-perl
  libref-util-perl libref-util-xs-perl libroken18-heimdal:i386 libsane
  libsane:i386 libsane1:i386 libsereal-perl libshine3:i386 libsnappy1v5:i386
  libsnmp35 libsnmp40:i386 libsoxr0:i386 libsrt1 libstruct-dumb-perl
  libswresample3:i386 libtepl-4-0 libtest-fatal-perl libtest-metrics-any-perl
  libtest-refcount-perl libtinyxml2-6a libtracker-control-2.0-0
  libtracker-miner-2.0-0 libtype-tiny-perl libtype-tiny-xs-perl libusrsctp1
  libva-drm2:i386 libva-x11-2:i386 libva2:i386 libvdpau1:i386 libvpx6:i386
  libwebp6:i386 libwebpmux3:i386 libwind0-heimdal:i386 libwrap0:i386
  libx264-155 libx264-155:i386 libx264-163:i386 libx265-179 libx265-179:i386
  libx265-199:i386 libxml-writer-perl libxmlb1 libxvidcore4:i386
  libyaml-cpp0.6 libzvbi0:i386 mesa-va-drivers:i386 mesa-vdpau-drivers:i386
  nextcloud-desktop-doc odbcinst odbcinst1debian2 perl-modules-5.30
  python-pip-whl python-wxgtk3.0 python-wxversion python3-entrypoints
  python3-simplebayes python3-termcolor python3.8 python3.8-dev
  python3.8-minimal va-driver-all:i386 vdpau-driver-all:i386
  x11proto-input-dev x11proto-randr-dev x11proto-xext-dev
  x11proto-xinerama-dev
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 209 to remove and 22 not upgraded.
1 not fully installed or removed.
After this operation, 735 MB disk space will be freed.
Do you want to continue? [Y/n] y
(Reading database ... 348806 files and directories currently installed.)
Removing coinor-libcoinmp1v5:amd64 (1.8.3-3) ...
Removing coinor-libcbc3:amd64 (2.10.7+ds1-1) ...
Removing coinor-libcgl1:amd64 (0.60.3+repack1-3) ...
Removing coinor-libclp1 (1.17.5+repack1-1) ...
Removing coinor-libosi1v5:amd64 (0.108.6+repack1-2) ...
Removing coinor-libcoinutils3v5:amd64 (2.11.4+repack1-2) ...
Removing cryptsetup-run (2:2.4.3-1ubuntu1.1) ...
Removing fonts-inter (3.19+ds-2) ...
dpkg: warning: while removing fonts-inter, directory '/usr/share/fonts/opentype/
inter' not empty so not removed
Removing gcc-10-base:i386 (10.3.0-15ubuntu1) ...
Removing gcc-10-base:amd64 (10.3.0-15ubuntu1) ...
Removing gir1.2-clutter-gst-3.0:amd64 (3.0.27-2ubuntu1) ...
Removing gir1.2-gtkclutter-1.0:amd64 (1.8.4-4build2) ...
Removing gir1.2-handy-0.0:amd64 (0.0.13-3) ...
Removing va-driver-all:i386 (2.14.0-1) ...
Removing i965-va-driver:i386 (2.4.1+dfsg1-1) ...
Removing intel-media-va-driver:i386 (22.3.1+dfsg1-1ubuntu1) ...
Removing kde-cli-tools (4:5.24.4-0ubuntu1) ...
Removing kde-cli-tools-data (4:5.24.4-0ubuntu1) ...
Removing libtepl-4-0:amd64 (4.4.0-1) ...
Removing libamtk-5-0:amd64 (5.2.0-1) ...
Removing libamtk-5-common (5.2.0-1) ...
Removing libaom0:amd64 (1.0.0.errata1-3build1) ...
Removing libaom0:i386 (1.0.0.errata1-3build1) ...
Removing libavcodec58:i386 (7:4.4.2-0ubuntu0.22.04.1) ...
Removing libaom3:i386 (3.3.0-1) ...
Removing libopenimageio2.1:amd64 (2.1.12.0~dfsg0-1) ...
Removing libopencv-videoio4.2:amd64 (4.2.0+dfsg-5) ...
Removing libopencv-imgcodecs4.2:amd64 (4.2.0+dfsg-5) ...
Removing libgdal26 (3.0.4+dfsg-1build3) ...
Removing libarmadillo9 (1:9.800.4+dfsg-1build1) ...
Removing libldap-2.4-2:i386 (2.4.49+dfsg-2ubuntu1.9) ...
Removing libgssapi3-heimdal:i386 (7.7.0+dfsg-3ubuntu1) ...
Removing libheimntlm0-heimdal:i386 (7.7.0+dfsg-3ubuntu1) ...
Removing libkrb5-26-heimdal:i386 (7.7.0+dfsg-3ubuntu1) ...
Removing libhx509-5-heimdal:i386 (7.7.0+dfsg-3ubuntu1) ...
Removing libasync-mergepoint-perl (0.04-2.1) ...
Removing libswresample3:i386 (7:4.4.2-0ubuntu0.22.04.1) ...
Removing libavutil56:i386 (7:4.4.2-0ubuntu0.22.04.1) ...
Removing libboost-date-time1.71.0:amd64 (1.71.0-6ubuntu6) ...
Removing libboost-filesystem1.71.0:amd64 (1.71.0-6ubuntu6) ...
Removing libopenvdb6.2 (6.2.1-8ubuntu1.1) ...
Removing libboost-iostreams1.71.0:amd64 (1.71.0-6ubuntu6) ...
Removing libboost-locale1.71.0:amd64 (1.71.0-6ubuntu6) ...
Removing libbrlapi0.7:amd64 (6.0+dfsg-4ubuntu6) ...
Removing libcbor0.6:amd64 (0.6.0-0ubuntu1) ...
Removing libcdio18:amd64 (2.0.0-2) ...
Removing libcfitsio8:amd64 (3.470-3) ...
Removing libcloudproviders0:amd64 (0.3.1-2) ...
Removing libcodec2-0.9:i386 (0.9.2-2) ...
Removing libcodec2-0.9:amd64 (0.9.2-2) ...
Removing libcodec2-1.0:i386 (1.0.1-3) ...
Removing libsane:i386 (1.1.1-5) ...
Removing libsane1:i386 (1.1.1-5) ...
Removing libcurl3-gnutls:i386 (7.81.0-1ubuntu1.3) ...
Removing libdap25:amd64 (3.20.5-1) ...
Removing libdapclient6v5:amd64 (3.20.9-1) ...
Removing libdap27:amd64 (3.20.9-1) ...
Removing libdav1d5:i386 (0.9.2-1) ...
Removing libdc1394-22:amd64 (2.2.5-2.1) ...
Removing libdcmtk14 (3.6.4-2.1build2) ...
Removing libdns-export1109 (1:9.11.16+dfsg-3~ubuntu1) ...
Removing libdrm-intel1:i386 (2.4.110-1ubuntu1) ...
Removing libdvdread7:amd64 (6.1.0+really6.0.2-1) ...
Removing libepsilon1:amd64 (0.9.2+dfsg-4) ...
Removing libextutils-pkgconfig-perl (1.16-1.1) ...
Removing libffi7:i386 (3.3-5ubuntu1) ...
Removing libfluidsynth2:amd64 (2.1.1-2) ...
Removing libio-async-loop-epoll-perl (0.22-1) ...
Removing libio-async-perl (0.801-2) ...
Removing libfuture-perl (0.48-1) ...
Removing libperl5.30:i386 (5.30.0-9ubuntu0.2) ...
Removing libsnmp40:i386 (5.9.1+dfsg-1ubuntu2.2) ...
Removing libperl5.34:i386 (5.34.0-3ubuntu1) ...
Removing libgdbm-compat4:i386 (1.23-1) ...
Removing libgdbm6:i386 (1.23-1) ...
Removing libgdk-pixbuf2.0-0:i386 (2.40.2-2build4) ...
Removing libgdk-pixbuf-xlib-2.0-0:i386 (2.40.2-2build4) ...
Removing libgeos-3.8.0:amd64 (3.8.0-1build1) ...
Removing libgles2-mesa-dev:amd64 (22.0.5-0ubuntu0.1) ...
Removing libglew2.1:amd64 (2.1.0-4) ...
Removing libglu1-mesa:i386 (9.0.2-1) ...
Removing libsoxr0:i386 (0.1.3-4build2) ...
Removing libgomp1:i386 (12-20220319-1ubuntu1) ...
Removing libgupnp-1.2-0:amd64 (1.2.4-0ubuntu1) ...
Removing libhandy-0.0-0:amd64 (0.0.13-3) ...
Removing libhcrypto4-heimdal:i386 (7.7.0+dfsg-3ubuntu1) ...
Removing libnetcdf15:amd64 (1:4.7.3-1) ...
Removing libhdf5-103:amd64 (1.10.7+repack-4ubuntu2) ...
Removing libhdf5-hl-fortran-100:amd64 (1.10.7+repack-4ubuntu2) ...
Removing libhdf5-fortran-102:amd64 (1.10.7+repack-4ubuntu2) ...
Removing libheimbase1-heimdal:i386 (7.7.0+dfsg-3ubuntu1) ...
Removing libhogweed5:amd64 (3.5.1+really3.5.1-2ubuntu0.2) ...
Removing libhogweed5:i386 (3.5.1+really3.5.1-2ubuntu0.2) ...
Removing libicu66:i386 (66.1-2ubuntu2.1) ...
Removing libieee1284-3:i386 (0.2.11-14build2) ...
Removing libigdgmm11:amd64 (20.1.1+ds1-1) ...
Removing libigdgmm11:i386 (20.1.1+ds1-1) ...
Removing libigdgmm12:i386 (22.1.2+ds1-1) ...
Removing libopenexr24:amd64 (2.3.0-6ubuntu0.5) ...
Removing libilmbase24:amd64 (2.3.0-6build1) ...
Removing libjson-c4:amd64 (0.13.1+dfsg-7ubuntu0.3) ...
Removing libkf5attica5:amd64 (5.92.0-0ubuntu1) ...
Removing libkf5su-bin (5.92.0-0ubuntu1) ...
Removing libkf5su5:amd64 (5.92.0-0ubuntu1) ...
Removing libkf5pty5:amd64 (5.92.0-0ubuntu1) ...
Removing libkf5pty-data (5.92.0-0ubuntu1) ...
Removing libkf5pulseaudioqt2:amd64 (1.2-2build1) ...
Removing libkf5su-data (5.92.0-0ubuntu1) ...
Removing libkworkspace5-5 (4:5.24.4-0ubuntu1) ...
Removing liblinux-epoll-perl:amd64 (0.018-1build1) ...
Removing libllvm12:amd64 (1:12.0.1-19ubuntu3) ...
Removing libllvm12:i386 (1:12.0.1-19ubuntu3) ...
Removing libtest-metrics-any-perl (0.01-2) ...
Removing libmetrics-any-perl (0.07-1) ...
Removing libmozjs-68-0:amd64 (68.6.0-1ubuntu1) ...
Removing libmysqlclient21:i386 (8.0.30-0ubuntu0.22.04.1) ...
Removing libnettle7:i386 (3.5.1+really3.5.1-2ubuntu0.2) ...
Removing libnettle7:amd64 (3.5.1+really3.5.1-2ubuntu0.2) ...
Removing libpoppler-glib8:i386 (22.02.0-2) ...
Removing libpoppler118:i386 (22.02.0-2) ...
Removing libnss3:i386 (2:3.68.2-0ubuntu1.1) ...
Removing libnspr4:i386 (2:4.32-3build1) ...
Removing libntfs-3g883 (1:2017.3.23AR.3-3ubuntu1.2) ...
Removing libx265-179:i386 (3.2.1-1build1) ...
Removing libx265-199:i386 (3.5-2) ...
Removing libnuma1:i386 (2.0.14-3ubuntu2) ...
Removing libodbc1:amd64 (2.3.9-5) ...
Removing libodbc1:i386 (2.3.9-5) ...
Removing libodbccr2:i386 (2.3.9-5) ...
Removing libodbccr2:amd64 (2.3.9-5) ...
Removing libofa0:amd64 (0.9.3-21) ...
Removing libopencv-imgproc4.2:amd64 (4.2.0+dfsg-5) ...
Removing libopencv-core4.2:amd64 (4.2.0+dfsg-5) ...
Removing libopengl0:i386 (1.4.0-1) ...
Removing libopenjp2-7:i386 (2.4.0-6) ...
Removing libpangox-1.0-0:amd64 (0.0.2-5ubuntu1) ...
Removing libpci3:i386 (1:3.7.0-6) ...
Removing libpciaccess0:i386 (0.16-3) ...
Removing libpcre2-posix2:amd64 (10.34-7) ...
Removing libsnmp35:amd64 (5.8+dfsg-2ubuntu2.5) ...
Removing libperl5.30:amd64 (5.30.0-9ubuntu0.2) ...
Removing libpgm-5.2-0:amd64 (5.2.122~dfsg-3ubuntu1) ...
Removing libpoppler97:amd64 (0.86.1-0ubuntu1) ...
Removing libproj15:amd64 (6.3.1-1) ...
Removing python3.8-dev (3.8.10-0ubuntu1~20.04.5) ...
Removing libpython3.8-dev:amd64 (3.8.10-0ubuntu1~20.04.5) ...
Removing libpython3.8:amd64 (3.8.10-0ubuntu1~20.04.5) ...
Removing python3.8 (3.8.10-0ubuntu1~20.04.5) ...
Removing libpython3.8-stdlib:amd64 (3.8.10-0ubuntu1~20.04.5) ...
Removing python3.8-minimal (3.8.10-0ubuntu1~20.04.5) ...
Unlinking and removing bytecode for runtime python3.8
Removing libpython3.8-minimal:amd64 (3.8.10-0ubuntu1~20.04.5) ...
Removing libqhull7:amd64 (2015.2-4) ...
Removing libqpdf26:amd64 (9.1.1-1ubuntu0.1) ...
Removing libraw19:amd64 (0.19.5-1ubuntu1) ...
Removing libre2-5:amd64 (20200101+dfsg-1build1) ...
Removing libreadonly-perl (2.050-3) ...
Removing libref-util-perl (0.204-1) ...
Removing libref-util-xs-perl (0.117-1build5) ...
Removing libwind0-heimdal:i386 (7.7.0+dfsg-3ubuntu1) ...
Removing libsane:amd64 (1.1.1-5) ...
Removing libsereal-perl (4.023-1) ...
Removing libshine3:i386 (3.1.1-2) ...
Removing libsnappy1v5:i386 (1.1.8-1build3) ...
Removing libsrt1:amd64 (1.4.0-1build1) ...
Removing libstruct-dumb-perl (0.12-1) ...
Removing libtest-fatal-perl (0.016-1) ...
Removing libtest-refcount-perl (0.10-1) ...
Removing libtinyxml2-6a:amd64 (7.0.0+dfsg-1build1) ...
Removing libtracker-control-2.0-0:amd64 (2.3.6-0ubuntu1) ...
Removing libtracker-miner-2.0-0:amd64 (2.3.6-0ubuntu1) ...
Removing libtype-tiny-perl (1.012004-1) ...
Removing libtype-tiny-xs-perl (0.022-1build2) ...
Removing libusrsctp1:amd64 (0.9.3.0+20190901-1) ...
Removing libva-drm2:i386 (2.14.0-1) ...
Removing libva-x11-2:i386 (2.14.0-1) ...
Removing libva2:i386 (2.14.0-1) ...
Removing vdpau-driver-all:i386 (1.4-3build2) ...
Removing mesa-vdpau-drivers:i386 (22.0.5-0ubuntu0.1) ...
Removing libvdpau1:i386 (1.4-3build2) ...
Removing libvpx6:i386 (1.8.2-1build1) ...
Removing libwebp6:i386 (0.6.1-2ubuntu0.20.04.1) ...
Removing libwebpmux3:i386 (1.2.2-2) ...
Removing libwrap0:i386 (7.6.q-31build2) ...
Removing libx264-155:amd64 (2:0.155.2917+git0a84d98-2) ...
Removing libx264-155:i386 (2:0.155.2917+git0a84d98-2) ...
Removing libx264-163:i386 (2:0.163.3060+git5db6aa6-2build1) ...
Removing libx265-179:amd64 (3.2.1-1build1) ...
Removing libxml-writer-perl (0.900-1) ...
Removing libxmlb1:amd64 (0.1.15-2ubuntu1~20.04.1) ...
Removing libxvidcore4:i386 (2:1.3.7-1) ...
Removing libyaml-cpp0.6:amd64 (0.6.2-4ubuntu1) ...
Removing libzvbi0:i386 (0.2.35-19) ...
Removing mesa-va-drivers:i386 (22.0.5-0ubuntu0.1) ...
Removing nextcloud-desktop-doc (3.5.4-20220806.084713.fea986309-1.0~focal1) ...
Removing odbcinst1debian2:amd64 (2.3.9-5) ...
Removing odbcinst (2.3.9-5) ...
Removing perl-modules-5.30 (5.30.0-9ubuntu0.2) ...
Removing python-pip-whl (20.0.2-5ubuntu1.6) ...
Removing python-wxgtk3.0 (3.0.2.0+dfsg-8build1) ...
Removing python-wxversion (3.0.2.0+dfsg-8build1) ...
Removing python3-entrypoints (0.4-1) ...
Removing python3-simplebayes (1.5.7-2) ...
Removing python3-termcolor (1.1.0-3) ...
Removing x11proto-input-dev (2021.5-1) ...
Removing x11proto-randr-dev (2021.5-1) ...
Removing x11proto-xext-dev (2021.5-1) ...
Removing x11proto-xinerama-dev (2021.5-1) ...
Removing libasn1-8-heimdal:i386 (7.7.0+dfsg-3ubuntu1) ...
Removing libroken18-heimdal:i386 (7.7.0+dfsg-3ubuntu1) ...
Setting up usrmerge (25ubuntu2) ...
Smartmatch is experimental at /usr/lib/usrmerge/convert-usrmerge line 172.

FATAL ERROR:
Both /lib/libeToken.so.10 and /usr/lib/libeToken.so.10 exist.

You can try correcting the errors reported and running again
/usr/lib/usrmerge/convert-usrmerge until it will complete without errors.
Do not install or update other Debian packages until the program
has been run successfully.

dpkg: error processing package usrmerge (--configure):
 installed usrmerge package post-installation script subprocess returned error e
xit status 1
Processing triggers for fontconfig (2.13.1-4.2ubuntu5) ...
Processing triggers for desktop-file-utils (0.26-1ubuntu3) ...
Processing triggers for gnome-menus (3.36.0-1ubuntu3) ...
Processing triggers for libc-bin (2.35-0ubuntu3.1) ...
Processing triggers for man-db (2.10.2-1) ...
Processing triggers for mailcap (3.70+nmu1ubuntu1) ...
Errors were encountered while processing:
 usrmerge
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
iulian@iulian-md:~$ sudo apt --fix-broken install
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree... Done
Reading state information... Done
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 22 not upgraded.
1 not fully installed or removed.
After this operation, 0 B of additional disk space will be used.
Setting up usrmerge (25ubuntu2) ...
Smartmatch is experimental at /usr/lib/usrmerge/convert-usrmerge line 172.

FATAL ERROR:
Both /lib/libeToken.so.10 and /usr/lib/libeToken.so.10 exist.

You can try correcting the errors reported and running again
/usr/lib/usrmerge/convert-usrmerge until it will complete without errors.
Do not install or update other Debian packages until the program
has been run successfully.

dpkg: error processing package usrmerge (--configure):
 installed usrmerge package post-installation script subprocess returned error e
xit status 1
Errors were encountered while processing:
 usrmerge
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
iulian@iulian-md:~$
```

Comment: Step 1: Read the line in your output marked `FATAL ERROR`. Verify that it's true (not a mistake).

Answer (score 1):

I have now solved my usrmerge FATAL error on upgrading from Ubuntu 20.04LTS to 22.04LTS. usrmerge basically tidies up software installations and most Linux variants have installed it automatically now; Ubuntu included in 2020?  Some old software however has been stuck in more than one path and triggers the “exists in two places error” which has to be manually corrected. My upgrade left me with no access to the internet,but a working desktop and Terminal. Your FATAL error will be different. My FATAL error was:

**Both lib/systemd/system/sav-update.service and usr/lib/systemd/system/sav-update.service exist**   (I need to find sav-update.service)

1. Open **Terminal** and choosing **lib** first
2. **cd  /lib** (type a space after cd) moves to lib directory
3. **ls -l** (type a space after ls) (nb l not the number 1) This produces a lot of information in lib including dates when files/directories were installed and shows **systemd** my next directory.
   You could just type **ls** but I needed **ls -l** to see sav-update.service eventually.
4. **cd systemd** (no extra space after cd)
5. **ls -l** as above now showing **systemd** files and directories.
6. **cd system** (as before no extra space; you can see the path forwards probably in blue)
7. **ls -l** (As before. There it is,**sav-update.service** and interestingly installed in October 2018 one of the oldest files in the directory. You can repeat all these steps starting in your /usr/lib.... and find the other existing file. Now which one to delete? I am not sure it matters but I chose to do this in /lib not usr/lib
8. You return to the $ prompt by typing **cd**
9. (Thanks to the Mint website for the next step.) I was too scared of deleting something important so decided to rename the **sav-update.service** file.
   From the $ prompt.
   **sudo mv**(space)**/lib/systemd/system/sav-update.service**(space)**/lib/systemd/system/sav-update.service.old** then enter your Ubuntu password as usual. You can check to see the new file with .old on the end is in /lib/systemd/system if you want.
10. Now following the error advice which you probably received about running convert-usrmerge again. At the $ prompt again **sudo**(space)**/usr/lib/usrmerge/convert-usrmerge**

Now I received a new error message saying sav-protect.service existed in /lib... and /usr/lib... Repeating the same procedures to rename this and again for sav-rms.service led me to a final new message **successful installation**. A reboot brought my internet leaping into action. Now I think **sav** related to Sophos Antivirus that I downloaded via their website in 2018 and have long since removed. My apologies to Linux experts. I look at this as a beginner (like me) would.

Answer (score 0):

Try to make `sudo apt autoremove` and solve the conflits before install the new Ubuntu version

Answer (score 0):

I got the following error, too.

```
FATAL ERROR:
Both /lib/systemd/system/sav-rms.service and /usr/lib/systemd/system/sav-rms.service exist
```

The solution was simple: just rename the file with duplication, such as `sudo mv /usr/lib/systemd/system/sav-rms.service /usr/lib/systemd/system/sav-rms.service.old`
'

This service belongs to Sophos Anti-Virus, even if you rename it, if it is still running, then it will recreate the file straightaway, therefore, first stop the service and then rename the file.
To stop the service run:

```
sudo systemctl stop sav-rms.service
```

Then do the renaming that I provided earlier. If there are more clashes, do rename (or completely remove) them too.